# How to install my program on windows startup

Tags: windows, installation, reboot

I'm trying to figure out how to install software when the PC reboots Note that this is on machine startup, not user login. Anyone have any suggestions? Google searches just return how to set programs to start on user login. That's not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few puzzle pieces to unravel here:

1. Choosing a mechanism for running on startup prior to user login.  For this, the fact that your task is installation of further software doesn't matter.  A "service" is the usual way to do this, although for example antivirus software tends to use device drivers.
2. Automating scheduling your code to run at startup.  If you chose a service in the above step, this means using the Service Control Manager API.
3. Actually doing the work, without having an active user login session.  Services run in an environment where there is no UI available, the user registry is associated with a service account and not any real user, etc.  Other than that, code runs normally (you can load DLLs, access files and directories, etc).  Permissions needed by your installer may also become a problem and cause you to modify the service installation options in step 2.